# Process.StandardOutput.ReadLine() not "syncing" properly

Tags: c#, .net

I've tried to read up on a few articles about this, but some of them were over my head at the moment.

I run a program that re-caches some SQL data from an external source. I call this from a WinForm application which manipulates the aforementioned data.

While the Console app is running, I lay over the controls with a panel (with a textbox on it) and try to capture the Console app's stdout into the textbox. It "works", but has some issues with repeating lines and missing lines. Reading the stream **after** the process ends works fine, but I'm having issues with real-time.

[CODE](http://pastebin.com/FgZtHPiQ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked well for me in asynchronous way. Unfortunately I'm not so familiar with .net to write code from my memory...

Upd:
Spent a couple of minutes and found the page in MSDN. Use Process.BeginOutputReadLine Method, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.beginoutputreadline.aspx) is the description of the function and a sample of its usage.

Comment: Thanks a ton. I knew there had to be an easier way to do this than some of the ways I saw.